# No iOs templates in XCode 4.2

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I installed Lion, then XCode 4.2 from the app store.

As I understand, the iOs SDK should be install with this release.

My problem is, I only get the MacOs templates, no iOs templates.

What am I doing wrong? (It's taking Apple a few weeks now to process my company enrollment and I need to start coding so long).

Comment: It's a clean install of XCode. No other plugins or "stuff" installed.

Answer (score 1):

While installing you need to check that you want to install iOS 5.X SDK, it doesn't install automatically. Re-run the "Install Xcode" application which AppStore downloaded and check to install iOS SDK

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform exists.  If so, then iOS files were installed.

The iOS templates are contained in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/XCode/Templates

If they are there, but are not showing up in XCode, you can try repairing disk permissions with /Applications/Utilities/"Disk Utility".

Otherwise, you may have to rename the /Developer folder and re-install.